# How to call a component from a CSV file withe the number of row and the name of column

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a `csv` file with 1000 rows and 1000 columns

I have just found that I can call each component from specific rows and columns using

```
df = pd.read_csv('name.csv', sep=",")

print(df.iloc[120, 250])
```

which means I am calling component from row `120` and column `250`.

but my question is, how can I call a component with its name of column and the value of its row not the values of its column and the value of its row.

for example the name or row of column 1 is 23
for column 2 I have 43
for column 3 the first row is 55

If I write `df.iloc[0, 2]` it will be `55` and `df.iloc[0, 0]` is `23`,I want instead of writing the value of column (for example 2 or 0 or 6) to force the code to give values of column starting with `55` or `23`

Comment: `df.iloc` is for numeric indexing, `df.loc` is for named indexing. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @G.Anderson Because the number of columns is too much instead of searching for specific value of the column I want to user say, python give the value of row `800` and the column which starts with `78` another one the user can write the value of row `720` and the column that starts with `12`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about accesing a value by the name of the column and number of row in
`df.at[index:column]`